# Injecting dependancies - Doctrine: Multiple repositories vs single entity manager

Tags: php, database, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

I have a service class that has dependencies on multiple entity repositories, for example 4.
I could inject each repository and end up with many dependencies, or I could inject the entity manager as a single dependency; relying on `EntityManager->getRepo('xyz')`.

Separate dependencies has the benefit of code hinting.

Single dependency means less verbose at construct.
Possibly easier mocking and less setup?

What is considered a better practice?

Comment: Repository injection wins hands down.  The real problem is that any class that depends on 4 repositories is probably doing too much.

Comment: I agree that it does seem excessive,. However it maybe that some of the repos should be merged as it's a combination of formElement, formElementOption, formElementFilter etc..  so, much of it is possibly over normalised.  But I appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case EntityManager is something like [Service Locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern). When service depends on EntityManager, it also formally depends on all its API and all related objects (repositories, metatada, etc). Better inject only what you really need:
explicit injection of specific repositories makes your service easier to read and test.

Also, prefer interface over class if possible (ObjectRepository instead of EntityRepository, ObjectManager instead of EntityManager).

Answer (score 2):

I assume, that you must use only one Doctrine Entity Manager in your service dependencies. 
But if you want to have code hinting in your IDE, you can do it with phpdoc annotation like this

```
class SomeServiceWithDoctrineDependency
{
    /** @var YourFirstObjectRepository */
    protected $firstRepo;
    /** @var YourSecondObjectRepository */
    protected $secondRepo;
    /** @var YourThirdObjectRepository */
    protected $thirdRepo;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->firstRepo = $entityManager->getRepository('First:Repo');
        $this->secondRepo = $entityManager->getRepository('Second:Repo');
        $this->thirdRepo = $entityManager->getRepository('Third:Repo');
    }

    public function getCodeHint()
    {
        // You get hint here for find method
        // $this->thirdRepo()->find()... 
    }
}
```